# Calculate total variance in power bi with dax

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 3 measures:

```
1) total_trx = SUM(mytable[trx])
2) trx_prev_month = CALCULATE([total_trx], DATEADD(calendar[date], -1,MONTH))
3) monthly_var = DIVIDE([total_trx],[trx_prev_month])-1
```

If I add a waterfall viz, x-axis with month, it gives me the % of monthly variation and a TOTAL bar at the end that sums all the variations.
I need to reproduce that total number in order to show a KPI as in "so far, we've increased ...%", changing  when using a date slicer.

Seems like sum(monthly_var) is not allowed.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much.

Edit1: sample with date filter = Last 4 months

```
Jul 100   0%
Aug 110  10%
Sep  90 -20%
Oct  80 -10%
```

Total: -20% <- need a dax to calculate this number and show just -20%

Then if I change the filter to, for example LAST 6 MONTHS, I need to calculate it up to May

Comment: Can you add some sample data and your expected output from them?

Comment: Thanks mkRabbani, I tried to put an example of what I need to calculate. Hope that helps .

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the desired result we will use an intermediate table in our query that will summarize the results by months:

use this code and replace `calendar[Year Month]` with your Year month column :

```
SUMX(
      SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(calendar[Year Month],"Monthly_int_var",[monthly_var]),
      [Monthly_int_var]
    )
```

Comment: thanks @BOUBRIT Nacim, still trying to make that work to see what number it displays, but it keeps showing errors

Comment: Have u changed calendar[Year Month] with your year Month culumn.